# CUDA: Get subset of 3D Surface

Tags: c++, c, 3d, cuda, geometry-surface

I want to render some slices of a 3d surface.

```
cudaArray* surfArray;
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(8, 8, 8, 8, cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned);
cudaExtent surfSize = make_cudaExtent(640,480,2);
cudaMalloc3DArray(&surfArray,&channelDesc,surfSize,cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore);
```

Therefore, I tried to get the subsets via MemcpyArrayToArray() and an offset.

```
cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&cu_rgbArray,tex_rgb,0,0);
cudaMemcpyArrayToArray(cu_rgbArray,0,0,surfArray,0,0,640*480*sizeof(uchar4),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&cu_depthArray,tex_depth,0,0);
cudaMemcpyArrayToArray(cu_depthArray,0,0,surfArray,640,480,640*480*sizeof(uchar4),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

However, while the first memcpy succeeds, the second one fails.
(It does succeed if the offset is 0,0).

Any thoughts how to get around this problem without an extra kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `cudaMemcpy3D`, not `cudaMemcpyArrayToArray`.